# Trying to get meaningful data from an output text file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a text file that looks as below. Please note that I have replaced junk data with "junkdata". It is just data which is not of use to me at the moment, along with blank lines.

```
junkdata 1

uid=1

junkdata 2
junkdata 3
junkdata 4

abc value1 def
pqr value1 kjks
sds value1 9982
asd value1 qwe

junkdata 5
junkdata 6
junkdata 7

uid=2

junkdata 8
junkdata 9
junkdata 10

aas value2 dg
sds value2 kwq
sdf value2 99wqa
gffs value2 ddg

junkdata11
junkdata12
junkdata13
```

I am looking to get data in the following format using powershell:

```
value   uid 
-----   ---   
Value1   1
Value2   2
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it should work.Tested using your example.

```
$FileListArray = @()
$FilesName = "c:\test\t1.txt"
    Foreach($file in Get-Content $FilesName | Where-Object {$_ -match "(uid\=\d)|(value\d)"})
    {
      IF($file -match "(value\d)")
        {$file = $file -replace "(.+)(value\d)(.+)",'$2' 
         $FileListArray += ,@($file)
        }

      Else{$FileListArray += ,@($file)}
    } 
$FileListArray
```

Comment: I am fine with the format of the output, the main concern is eliminating the junk data. I am ok even if the output is on another text file or  an array

Comment: wowwwwwww.. that was awesome.. thanks a lot .. just what I needed